# Remove jQuery dependency on simple text rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment I am loading a whole jQuery library for something that is really rather simple. It relates through a list of span's which each contain different text, so that the message is different each time.

Here is the code that I have:

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 
        rotaterator: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                fadeSpeed: 500,
                pauseSpeed: 500,
                child:null
            };

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                  var o =options;
                  var obj = $(this);                
                  var items = $(obj.children(), obj);
                  items.each(function() {$(this).hide();})
                  if(!o.child){var next = $(obj).children(':first');
                  }else{var next = o.child;
                  }
                  $(next).fadeIn(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
                        $(next).delay(o.pauseSpeed).fadeOut(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
                            var next = $(this).next();
                            if (next.length == 0){
                                    next = $(obj).children(':first');
                            }
                            $(obj).rotaterator({child : next, fadeSpeed : o.fadeSpeed, pauseSpeed : o.pauseSpeed});
                        })
                    });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.rotate').rotaterator({fadeSpeed:500, pauseSpeed:6000});
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="light content-medium center text-center soft-top--quad">
Join us for a
    <div class="rotate"> 
        <span>relaxed</span>
        <span>wonderful</span>
       <span>crazy</span>
    </div> 
  weekend of
  <div class="rotate"> 
        <span>fun</span>
        <span>games</span>
        <span>laughter</span>
       <span>dancing</span>
     <span>love</span>
  </div> resulting in your
  <div class="rotate"> 
        <span>best</span>
        <span>worst</span>
        <span>most disgusting</span>
    </div>
     <div class="rotate"> 
        <span>memories</span>
        <span>hangover</span>
    </div>
      </h2>
```

I was hoping to re-implement this in vanilla JavaScript instead and wondered if this would be an easy job? For example, is there anything in here which relies heavily on jQuery?

How can I best start with this, as I am rather new to JavaScript?

Comment: Given that the whole block of code is a jQuery plugin, then yes, it relies heavily on jQuery. You will need to re-write the whole thing.

Comment: You should be able to rewrite the code using `Element.animate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you need a whole rewrite.
I took a look and wrote a vanilla script with the same functionality from scratch without caring about the previous logic.
I used CSS transitions instead of any JavaScript animation library.

Since this is a quick shot and nobody pays me, it's not the best and most efficient code and it could be improved using more functions and callbacks.

There are several `setTimeout` and multiple DOM updates.
We also have to care about the fact, that the other items should be hidden (using `display: none` so they don't use space) but we cannot fade in an already hidden item by setting `display: inline; opacity: 1` at the same moment, otherwise we wouldn't see the transition.

It could have been done **so much better in ES2015+** which fewer lines, arrow functions and `Promise`, but since I don't know where you need this script and which browser you want to support, I wrote it in ugly old plain ES5.

```
/**
 * The new fancy VanillaJS rotaterator
 * @param {string} selector 
 * @param {object} options 
 */
function rotaterator(selector, options) {
    var defaults = {
        fadeSpeed: 500,
        pauseSpeed: 500,
        child: null
    };

    var options = Object.assign(defaults, options);
    var items = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    var allSpans = [];

    /**
     * Fade all elements of the given array in by setting display and opacity
     * @param {array} arrElements 
     */
    function fadeElementsIn(arrElements) {
        arrElements.forEach(function (e) {
            if (e.style.display === 'none') {
                // if we are setting from none directly to inline, we need a small delay
                e.style.display = 'inline';
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    e.style.opacity = 1;
                }, 10);
            } else
                e.style.opacity = 1;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Hide all previously cached span elements by setting display to none
     */
    function hideAll() {
        allSpans.forEach(function (e) {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }

    /**
     * Set initial styles and transition and fade first elements in
     */
    function initialize(onInitialized) {
        var initialFadeIn = [];
        items.forEach(function (item) {
            var spans = item.querySelectorAll('span');
            spans.forEach(function (span) {
                allSpans.push(span);
                span.style.opacity = 0;
                span.style.transition = (options.fadeSpeed / 1000) + 's linear';
            });

            initialFadeIn.push(spans[0]);
        });

        // finally fade the first set of elements in and call the callback
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            fadeElementsIn(initialFadeIn);
            onInitialized();
        }, 10);
    }

    /**
     * Fade the current items out and fade the next items in
     */
    function next() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            var toFadeIn = [];

            items.forEach(function (item) {
                var nextIndex;
                for (var i = 0; i < item.children.length; i++) {
                    if (item.children[i].style.opacity == 1) {
                        // fade current item out
                        item.children[i].style.opacity = 0;

                        // set next index to fadeIn
                        nextIndex = (i + 1 > item.children.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1);
                    }
                }

                // save the next element to array
                toFadeIn.push(item.children[nextIndex]);
            });

            // wait for fade out transition effect to complete and then fade all new elements in
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                hideAll();
                fadeElementsIn(toFadeIn);

                // after fadeIn transition effect call this method recursive.
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    next();
                }, options.fadeSpeed);
            }, options.fadeSpeed);
        }, options.pauseSpeed);
    }

    initialize(next);
}

ready(function () {
    rotaterator('.rotate', { fadeSpeed: 500, pauseSpeed: 6000 });
});

/**
 * Polyfill for Object.assign
 */
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
    Object.assign = function (target) {
        'use strict';
        if (target == null) {
            throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
        }

        target = Object(target);
        for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
            var source = arguments[index];
            if (source != null) {
                for (var key in source) {
                    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
                        target[key] = source[key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return target;
    };
}

/**
 * document.ready function without jQuery
 * @param {function} fn 
 */
function ready(fn) {
    if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading") {
        fn();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
    }
}
```